# Inserting a string inside of a javascript defined in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, string

I just found myself in an odd position trying to put a string inside of javascript, that is defined in a php. The code I'm going to post isn't that actual code, but its the situation I'm in.

```
$script = "
var someVar = \"<input type='text' onchange='callScript('problem here') />' \";
";
```

so as you see, I'm setting a javascript variable that has html elements in it. the html element has an onchange event that is set to call a function that takes a string as a parameter. How would i insert that parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you call `addslashes()` on the string before inserting it into the variable, you should be fine as to escaping any possible unsafe characters, so:

```
$script = "var someVar = \"<input type='text' onchange='callScript(\\\"".addslashes($problem_here)."\\\") />' \";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.fromCharCode`:

```
$script = "
var someVar = \"<input type='text' onchange='callScript(\" + String.fromCharCode(34) + \"problem here\" + String.fromCharCode(34) + \") />' \";
";
```

Generated JavaScript would be:

```
var someVar = "<input type='text' onchange='callScript(" + String.fromCharCode(34) + "problem here" + String.fromCharCode(34) + ") />' \";
```

which evaluates to `someVar` being the string

```
<input type='text' onchange='callScript("problem here") />'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$script = "
var someVar = \"<input type='text' onchange='callScript(\"problem here\")' />\" ";
```

Comment: this won't work because the someVar's string gets cut off in the callScript

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your JavaScript will be inside a view file, so you won't print it out with PHP, more the other way around:

```
var jsVar = <?php echo json _encode($phpstring); ?>;
```

Or the shorter:

```
var jsVar = <?=json_encode($phpstring)?>;
```

Json encode will make sure the string is printed in a way that it will be read properly by JS.
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

In general, stay away from `addslashes`.  Do what Robin Winslow said (I'm new here so I guess I can't reply directly) and use `json_encode`.

However, you'd still need to html-escape your that string in JS.  Look into something like jQuery's templating system if you're generating HTML with JS.